# Azure CDN Rules Engine add www to naked domain

Tags: azure, cdn

I am hosting a static website in Azure storage using an Azure endpoint to expose it to users.

I have successfully set up a rule that automatically forwards an HTTP request to HTTPS.

Because Microsoft CDN no longer supports certificates on the naked domain. I want to create a rule that automatically prefixes www to the address.

e.g. if a user types in example.com the rules process would change the request to https://www.example.com.

The first rule is working, but the second isn't. It's actually creating too many redirections errors when I try to use the naked domain to access the site.

Here are the rules I currently have setup. There are plenty of examples on the web for the Verizon engine, but I'm using the Microsoft one.

[image]

Comment: have you found a solution for this?

Comment: I couldn't get this to work with Azure CDN either. After trying out multiple things, I ended up setting up Cloudflare, which in turn points to Azure CDN. So now I have 2 CDNs in place, which is quite redundant.

Answer (score 0):

Azure DNS Alias records seem to be the official answer:

> Azure DNS alias records are qualifications on a DNS record set. They
> can reference other Azure resources from within your DNS zone. For
> example, you can create an alias record set that references an Azure
> public IP address instead of an A record. Your alias record set points
> to an Azure public IP address service instance dynamically. As a
> result, the alias record set seamlessly updates itself during DNS
> resolution.
> [Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dns/dns-alias]

You can read more about Alias records here: https://www.dnsinfozone.com/what-is-an-alias-record/.

Once you have the Apex\Root\Naked domain routing to the domain.com via an Alias record you can set up a redirect on the CDN, under settings > rules engine > + Add Rule where you can Add a Condition = domain.com and an Action = [www.domain.com](http://www.domain.com) (See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/34737/how-to-point-your-dns-zone-apex-root-naked-domain.html and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/57881/how-to-redirect-from-a-root-domain-to-www-using-az.html)

That should allow you to use the HTTPS certificate provided by Azure on your www.domain.

Unfortunately, Alias Records aren't supported by other domain providers, e.g. Google Domains, so you may have to settle for a simple HTTP 301\302 redirect forwarding link. These can be applied using URLRewrite (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/url-rewriting?view=aspnetcore-6.0).

Another alternative, to routing naked domains to www.domains, is to "Bring your own" certificate and apply that to the CDN root domain.